# Why does example code access deleted memory in IUnknown?

Tags: c++, interface, c++builder

Quite a number of examples when using interfaces such as `IUnknown`, in this example `IDocHostUIHandler` but it doesn't really matter - use code similar to this:

```
 class TDocHostUIHandlerImpl : public IDocHostUIHandler
 {
 private:

    ULONG RefCount;

    public:      

    TDocHostUIHandlerImpl():RefCount(0){ }

    // IUnknown Method
    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv) {
        if (IsEqualIID(riid,IID_IUnknown))
            {
            *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
            return S_OK;
            }
        else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IDocHostUIHandler)) {
            *ppv = static_cast<IDocHostUIHandler*>(this);
            return S_OK;
            }
        else {
            *ppv = NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
            }
        }

    ULONG   __stdcall AddRef() {
        InterlockedIncrement((long*)&RefCount);
        return RefCount;
        }

    ULONG   __stdcall Release() {
        if (InterlockedDecrement((long*)&RefCount) == 0) delete this;
        return RefCount;
        }
```

My problem here is with the `Release()` method which deletes the interface implementation using `delete this` but immediately after that does `return RefCount` which no longer refers to a valid object in memory (it accesses deleted memory).

I would assume that it should be something like

```
    ULONG   __stdcall Release() {
        if (InterlockedDecrement((long*)&RefCount) == 0) { delete this; return 0; }
        return RefCount;
        }
```

Which also doesn't trigger resource leak tool which I use (Codeguard in C++ Builder). So why then so many examples use the first version, what am I missing here?

Or is it just the case that the "delete this" is called in another compiler like Visual Studio after the `Release` method ends?

A few examples:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4758/How-to-customize-the-context-menus-of-a-WebBrowser

[addref and release in IUnknown, what do they actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010172/addref-and-release-in-iunknown-what-do-they-actually-do)

https://bbs.csdn.net/topics/20135139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that such examples are badly written.  They need to be written more like you have described:

```cpp
ULONG __stdcall Release()
{
    if (InterlockedDecrement((long*)&RefCount) == 0) {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    return RefCount;
}
```

However, it is better for them to just return whatever result `InterlockedDecrement` returns.  As @RaymondChen pointed out in comments, this also addresses the issue of `RefCount` being decremented by another thread, potentially destroying `this`, before the `return` is reached, eg:

```cpp
ULONG __stdcall Release()
{
    ULONG res = (ULONG) InterlockedDecrement((long*)&RefCount);
    if (res == 0) {
        delete this;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Same with the `AddRef()`, for that matter:

```cpp
ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
{
    return (ULONG) InterlockedIncrement((long*)&RefCount);
}
```

---

On a side note, the `QueryInterface()` example you have shown is also written incorrectly, as it is not incrementing the `RefCount` when returning `S_OK`, eg:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    if (IsEqualIID(riid,IID_IUnknown)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
        AddRef(); // <-- add this!
        return S_OK;
    }
    else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IDocHostUIHandler)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IDocHostUIHandler*>(this);
        AddRef(); // <-- add this!
        return S_OK;
    }
    else {
        *ppv = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}
```

Which can typically be written more easily like this instead:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    if (!ppv) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IUnknown)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
    }
    else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IDocHostUIHandler)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IDocHostUIHandler*>(this);
    }
    else {
        *ppv = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

I've also seen it written like this, which accounts for bad cases when `QueryInterface()` is called on a `NULL` pointer:

```cpp
HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    if (!ppv) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IUnknown)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
    }
    else if (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IDocHostUIHandler)) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IDocHostUIHandler*>(this);
    }
    else {
        *ppv = NULL;
    }

    if (*ppv) {
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

Comment: The first version (`return RefCount`) is also wrong, because the object could have been released and destructed on another thread before the current thread can read `RefCount`. You have to do it the second way.